# Firebase V9 - Custom 'Doc ID' Upon Creation (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im wanting to create a doc in Firebase Firestore with Javascript... That doesn't just have the automatic generated ID

`return addDoc(collection(db, "users"), { bio: signupForm['signup-bio'].value });`

This is how I'm coding it could someone please show me where or how to add a custom ID to to the doc?

Thanks

Comment: `firebase.firestore().doc('yourCollection/' + customId).set({bio: value})`

Comment: Isn't this for version 8 and below?

Comment: Oh nevermind, did not see the version 9 in the title sorry

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I figured it out...

To create a custom ID for a new doc is as follows...

```
setDoc(doc(db, 'collection', 'ID'), { feild: value, feild: value });
```

or in my case as an example...

```
setDoc(doc(db, 'users', (cred.user.uid), { bio: signupForm['signup-bio'].value });
```

This creates a new doc (and the users collection if it doesn't exist already) with the ID being the current logged in users UserID and the data in the doc is the value from a signup form called 'signup-bio'

Answer (score 3):

For me the following worked:

```
    await setDoc(doc(db, "collection/" + newId), { field: value} )
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to set custom document IDs in *Firestore*, you need to use the `set` method instead of `add`:

```
db.collection("users").doc("YOUR_ID").set({
    bio: signupForm['signup-bio'].value
});
```

You can refer to the official documentation on how to [*Set a document*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) which states that:

> To create or overwrite a single document, use the set() method:

```
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
})
.then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

> If the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data, unless you specify that the data should be merged into the existing document...

Comment: Thanks for your response, 
Im getting 'db.collection is not a function' error when i try to run this

Comment: have you defined `const db = firebase.firestore()` ?

Answer (score 0):

For someone who using collection as variable / existing function.

Example in **Typescript** like this https://javascript.plainenglish.io/using-firestore-with-typescript-in-the-v9-sdk-cf36851bb099

Normal:

```
const docRef = doc(helloCol())
```

But **you can also do something like…**:

```
const docRef = doc(helloCol(), 'some-id')
// await setDoc(docRef, { /* data */ })
```

Without changing `helloCol()`

**Ref:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#doc